# Flutter bloc doesn't update the ui when the state was changed (The state is different)

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am new in flutter bloc. After learning the bloc,I have met a problem that the flutter bloc will not update the ui with different state.

See the simple application below which just increases the number. You can run it for test purpose:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

// Counter event.
abstract class CounterEvent {}
class Increment extends CounterEvent {}

// Counter bloc: Recive a event and increase the count.
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  CounterBloc() : super(0) {
    on<Increment>((Increment event, Emitter<int> emit) {
      print('Send state: ${state + 1}');
      emit(state + 1);
    });
  }
}

// Home page event and bloc here, just as a placeholder.
class HomeEvent {}
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, int> {
  HomeBloc() : super(0) {
    on<HomeEvent>((HomeEvent event, Emitter<int> emit) => emit(state + 1));
  }
}

// The parent widget, create a home bloc.
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => HomeBloc()..add(HomeEvent()),
      child: Builder(
        builder: _getHome,
      ));

  Widget _getHome(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Frame')),
        body: CounterPage(),
      );
}

// Our counter page, use bloc provider to create a new bloc.
class CounterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  CounterPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CounterPage> createState() => _CounterPageState();
}

class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  late final CounterBloc _bloc = CounterBloc();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => BlocProvider<CounterBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => _bloc,
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        switch (context.read<CounterBloc>().state) {
          case 1:
            return Center(
                child: AddWidget(
              count: 1,
            ));
          case 2:
            return Center(
                child: AddWidget(
              count: 2,
            ));
          default:
            return Center(
                child: AddWidget(
              count: context.read<CounterBloc>().state,
            ));
        }
      }));
}

// As the sub widget, use the counter bloc from context.
class AddWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddWidget({required this.count, super.key});

  final int count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            '$count',
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Send increment event.');
              context.read<CounterBloc>().add(Increment());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the console output:
[sent the different state but ui not reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd5Hz.png)

And the ui is always 0.
[always 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBVp1.png)

Please help.

I have changed the CounterPage to stateful or stateless widget. It not worked.
Maybe I have to change the parent widget state which is App here to rebuild all the children? But I also tried add this to button:

```
context.read<HomeBloc>().add(HomeEvent());
```

It not worked either...

Comment: Have you tried replacing `context.read` with `context.watch` inside that Builder

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Thanks a lot! It works. Also, I find that if I change the builder to the BlocBuilder, it works too!

Maybe I should read the document of bloc again.

Comment: Oh by the way if you use `context.watch`, it is recommended to only call it once on the builder, so you can assign it to a local variable. And if you use `BlocBuilder`, you can use the `state` parameter from the callback so you don't need `context.read` or `context.watch`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `context.watch` inside the `Builder`. It is also recommended to only call `context.watch` once, so you can assign it to a local variable.

```dart
Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  final state = context.watch<CounterBloc>().state;

  switch (state) {
    case 1:
      return Center(
          child: AddWidget(
        count: 1,
      ));
    case 2:
      return Center(
          child: AddWidget(
        count: 2,
      ));
    default:
      return Center(
          child: AddWidget(
        count: state,
      ));
  }
}),
```

The [flutter_bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts) package offers the [`BlocBuilder`](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocbuilder) widget which exposes `state` through its callback parameter, so you can use it right away:

```dart
BlocBuilder(builder: (context, state) {
  switch (state) {
    case 1:
      return Center(
          child: AddWidget(
        count: 1,
      ));
    case 2:
      return Center(
          child: AddWidget(
        count: 2,
      ));
    default:
      return Center(
          child: AddWidget(
        count: state,
      ));
  }
})
```